# Callback in with() returns null in laravel eloquent query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-relations

I'm trying to use laravel eloquent to process a query but it doesn't recognize the relationship

```php
$query = $site
    ->consumers()
    ->with([
        'transactions' => function($_query) use ($thresh) {
            $_query
                ->where('status', 'processed')
                ->where('approved', 1)
                ->selectRaw("SUM({$thresh} - value + bonus_value) AS total_points");
        }
    ])
    ->where('total_points', '<=', 5000);

dd($query->get()->toArray());
```

I have this code. When I add `selectRaw` in `transactions` relationship it returns nothing but when I remove it, it returns all the transactions associated with consumer. Also, `total_points` in `where` clause raises issue that `total_points` not found.

I'm basically trying to get consumers who have total points less than or equals to 5000.

Comment: Do not insert variables directly into your database query. Use placeholders as [described in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#selectraw). Also, one typically puts `select()` or `selectRaw()` methods first in the chain, though I don't think it makes any difference. Check your database query logs to see what SQL is being sent.

Comment: Also if you're selecting columns manually, it's always a good idea to include the primary and foreign keys of the `transactions` table.

Comment: @miken32 yes, there is no difference in the order in this case, but I am curious why use `$_query`, that is so strange, you always continue using `$query`. Follow PSR Ali.

Comment: You’re defining the function. You can call it’s parameter whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this could occur is because you have not set any relation that you are trying to retrieved. For example maybe the foreign keys column names are not correct or values mismatched.

lets say in `App/Models/Post.php` you have this relationship

```php
public function users(){

return $this->belongTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'user_id');
}
```

If the column `user_id` in post table is found but value did not match that off `App/Models/User.php` the relationship will return a null value when called. So, try checking your relationship foreign and local keys first.

Hope this helps you investigate you bug!